# does workflows work on cross objects?

Tags: workflow

Does workflows works on cross objects? I have a custom object having a picklist value and another standard object Accounts.If I update the picklist on custom object,it is possible to update the picklist on standard object with a particular value.I tried to use workflows but I think it is not possible.I alos tried to use process builder but that didn't work. Should I use trigger in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not update parent or child record using **Workflow** but, using **Process builder** you can do this. Below steps are for child record update using process builder but similarly you can update parent record as well.

> The Process Builder allows you to update child records whenever the
>   parent record is modified. Here's how:
>
> - Create a new Process.
> - Select the Object.
> - Define the Criteria.
> - In "Immediate Action," select Update Records.
> - Click on the "Object" drop down.
> - In "Find a field," look for the child object name you want to update.
> - If child object is a Custom Object the name would contain "__r" at the end.
> - Select the Child Object name, and then click Save.
> - In "Set Object Variables" portion, define the field that you want to update in child records.
> - Click Save.
>
> Similar steps can be used to **update lookup fields** using process
>   builder too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ashwani,Thanks for your help.I tried to update values on account object which is a parent object  but I could not find the 'type' field which is a picklist anywhere. Basically I want to change the type field value on account object which is a picklist when there is change in service status picklist field on a custom object.

Comment: It has Label `Account Type` @kunalgupta

Comment: Hi Aswani,I seached for Account type and type both but there isn't any field

Comment: Look at the image in answer in *Record* label I have selected `[Contact].AccountId`. You would see `[CustomObjectName__c].Account__c` or the name of lookup field `[CustomObjectName__c].AccountLookupField__c`. Then in last section you would be able to see All Account fields. I have selecte `Account Type` there. @kunalgupta